# Bash: Pipe output into a table

Tags: bash

I have a program that prints out the following:

```
bash-3.2$ ./drawgrid
0
1 1 0 
1 1 0 
0 0 0 
1
0 1 1 
0 1 1 
0 0 0 
2
0 0 0 
1 1 0 
1 1 0 
3
0 0 0 
0 1 1 
0 1 1
```

Is it possible to pipe the output of this command such that I get all the 3x3 matrices (together with their number) displayed on a table, for example a 2x2 like this?

```
0       1
1 1 0   0 1 1
1 1 0   0 1 1
0 0 0   0 0 0 
2       3
0 0 0   0 0 0 
1 1 0   0 1 1
1 1 0   0 1 1
```

I tried searching, and came across the *column* command, but I did not figure it out.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pr -2T` to get the following output, which is close to what you expected:

```
0                                   2
1 1 0                               0 0 0
1 1 0                               1 1 0
0 0 0                               1 1 0
1                                   3
0 1 1                               0 0 0
0 1 1                               0 1 1
0 0 0                               0 1 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an awk script:

```
NF == 1 {
    if ($NF % 2 == 0) {
        delete line
        line[1]=$1
        f=1
    } else {
        print line[1]"\t"$1
        f=0
    }
    n=1
}
NF > 1 {
    n++
    if (f)
        line[n]=$0
    else
        print line[n]"\t"$0
}
```

And pipe to it like so:

```
$ ./drawgrid | awk -f 2x2.awk
0       1
1 1 0   0 1 1 
1 1 0   0 1 1 
0 0 0   0 0 0 
2       3
0 0 0   0 0 0 
1 1 0   0 1 1 
1 1 0   0 1 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get exactly what you expect with a short bash script and a little array index thought:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a idx
declare -a acont
declare -i cnt=0
declare -i offset=0

while IFS=$'\n'; read -r line ; do

    [ ${#line} -eq 1 ] && { idx+=( $line ); ((cnt++)); }
    [ ${#line} -gt 1 ] && { acont+=( $line );((cnt++)); }

done

for ((i = 0; i < ${#idx[@]}; i+=2)); do

    printf "%4s%8s\n" ${idx[i]} ${idx[i+1]} 
    for ((j = offset; j < offset + 3; j++)); do
        printf " %8s%8s\n" ${acont[j]} ${acont[j+3]} 
    done
    offset=$((j + 3))
```

done

exit 0

**Output**

```
$ bash array_cols.sh <dat/cols.txt
   0       1
   1 1 0   0 1 1
   1 1 0   0 1 1
   0 0 0   0 0 0
   2       3
   0 0 0   0 0 0
   1 1 0   0 1 1
   1 1 0   0 1 1
```